# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named zenpy on PyCharm (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, pip, pycharm

I'm not too familiar with mac, but I fired up pycharm to run a script I made that uses the zenpy module. Problem is when I try to execute it, I get the error

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thisisfake/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/bin/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    from zenpy import Zenpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zenpy'
```

The obvious answer is, oh, I forgot to add the module to zenpy. So I went to File -> Preferences for New Projects -> Project Interpreter and added zenpy. Tried the script again, no dice. Check the project interpreter and zenpy is definitely there. I tried creating a new project entirely and re-adding it that way and no success. Tried moving the script to the bin folder, no luck. Added zenpy via pip in terminal, same result. I'm definitely missing something obvious, any idea what it is?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code, how you are using the module?

Comment: It looks like zenpy isn't installed in your `venv`, it may be installed for your machine's local copy of Python, but not your virtual environment. Trying running pip install from your venv instead. If it's already installed in your venv, does PyCharm's intellisense pickup anything for ZENPY?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select `View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal`
2. `pip install zenpy`

Comment: That was it, thank you! Learned something new about Pycharm as well.